# Cascaded DropDown Lists in JSP

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, jstl

I'm new to JSP i have tried to find a solution for my problem but unfortunately i couldn't. 
So what i m trying to do is to have 2 dropdowns and when i select a value from the first list second drop down must be filtered. 
And here's what i did so far :
Servlet passes below objects to jsp :

```
    getServletContext().setAttribute("foodDetails", fds.findAll());

    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
```

In jsp code i create two dropdowns and populate the lists using below code :

```
   <tr>
    <td>Detay Tipi 1</td>   
     <td>
       <select name="tip" id="tip" onchange="">     
         <option value="porsiyon">porsiyon</option>
         <option value="extra">extra</option>
       </select>  
     </td>
     <td>
        <select name="tip2" id="tip2" onchange="">
          <option value"Lütfen Tip Seçiniz">Lütfen Tip Seçiniz</option>
        </select>  
     </td>
   </tr>
```

So when user selects "porsiyon" from first dropdown,  second list will be populated with values from ${foodDetails}. To achieve this i overwrote first drop down's onchange method using below code :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#tip").change(function(){
     tip2.length = 1;
     var x=$(this).val();
     <c:forEach var="fd" items="${foodDetails}">
     <c:if test="${fd.detailcategory == x}"> 
     tip2.options[tip2.options.length]  = new Option("${fd.name}","${fd.name}");
     </c:if>
     </c:forEach>
       });
       });
</script>
```

this unfortunately doesn't work, when i switch

```
  var x=$(this).val();
```

with static value like :

```
  <c:set var="x" scope="session" value='ekstra'/>
```

it Works like charm where c is defined as :

```
  <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>.
```

I maybe doing a very obvious mistake but i can't figure out what. This is my first jsp page so go easy on me :) 
 PS : i don't think classes are needed to answer this but fooddetails has a list of fooddetail where fooddetail.detailcategory can be either "porsiyon" or "ekstra".

thanks,

Comment: i don't agree that this is a duplicate. i'm trying to go to backend to get some "values". I'm just trying to filter second list depending on the first dropdown value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related with your script not firing the `onchange` event, as you can see in the embebed snippet, instead, you're are trying to invoke JSTL functions in the client side and not in the server side.

You can try the following:

1. Create a JSP that builds up a JSON based response.
2. Call the JSP using  `AJAX`
3. Iterate thru your response in order to retrieve your filtered results.

Let's say that you have a foodDetails.jsp that receives a filtering parameter  called category.  With this parameter you can build  from the JSP a JSON based response.

#### foodDetails.jsp

```
"{filteredList: "
<c:forEach var="fd" "items="${foodDetails}">
    <c:if test="${fd.detailcategory == category}">
        "${fd.detailcategory},"     
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
"}"
```

### From you client-side (Web browser)

You can call the `foodDetails.jsp` using **AJAX** whenever the `onchange` event is fired...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#tip").change(function() {
    var category = jQuery(this).val();
    addFilteredItems(category);
});

function addFilteredItems(category) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/path/to/the/foodDetails.jsp?category=" + category,
        dataType: "json"
        _: jQuery.now()
    }).done(function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data, function(k, v) {
            var result = v["filteredList"];
            jQuery.each(result.split(","), function() {
                var item = jQuery(this).val();
                // add options
            });
        });
    });
}
```

### Snippet

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#tip").change(function(){
    var x= $(this).val();
    alert(x);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Detay Tipi 1</td>   
    <td>
      <select name="tip" id="tip" onchange="">     
        <option value="porsiyon">porsiyon</option>
        <option value="extra">extra</option>
      </select>  
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="tip2" id="tip2" onchange="">
        <option value"Lütfen Tip Seçiniz">Lütfen Tip Seçiniz</option>
      </select>  
    </td>
</tr>
```